# on a lemma in a paper by Mattila

Tags: real-analysis

In Mattila's article disproving the general form of Vitushkin's conjecture, we encounter the following sets:

$$B_m=\bigcup_{i=1}^{i_m}[5i\alpha_m,5i\alpha_m+1],$$

where $i_m$ is the largest integer ensuring that $[5i\alpha_m,5i\alpha_m+1]$ is fully contained in the interval $[0,\pi]$ and $\alpha_m$ is a sequence. Now, Mattila claims that, if we choose $\alpha_m$ going o $0$ fast enough, we have that for any $l$ and $k<l$

$$\left|[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{l+1} B_{m}\right|<(1-\varepsilon)\left|[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{l} B_{m}\right|.$$

Now, I am completely lost as to how to prove this. For $k=l$, this is not hard: choosing $\alpha_{l+1}$ small enough mean that $B_{l+1}$ is going to be made up of very dense small intervals and some calculations prove the result. The issue, however, is when we start trying to prove the result for $k$ small, since in that case it's an issue of trying to "avoid" many $B_i$, and it is not clear to me how to do that. Trying to go with an inductive construction also didn't seem to help, unfortunately. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It seems that something is wrong. You write that ''choosing $\alpha_{l+1}$ small enough mean that $B_{l+1}$ is going to be made up of very dense small intervals'', whereas if $0<\alpha_{l+1}\le 1/5$ then $B_{l+1}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{i_{l+1}}[5i\alpha_{l+1},5i\alpha_{l+1}+1]=[5\alpha_{l+1},5i_{l+1}\alpha_{l+1}+1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The paper in question is ["Smooth Maps, Null-Sets for Integralgeometric Measure and Analytic Capacity"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971273),
Pertti Mattila, *Annals of Mathematics*, ser. 2, **123** (1986), 303-309.)]

The definition of $B_m$ is
$$
B_m=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k_m} \ [5 i \alpha_m, (5i+1) \alpha_m], \qquad m=1, 2, \dots,
$$
and Mattila claims that you can choose $\alpha_m$ so that, if $1\le k<l$,
$$
\left|[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{l+1} B_m\right|
< (6/5)(4/5)
\left|[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{l} B_m\right|.\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
Now, induce on $l$.
Suppose that you have chosen $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\dots$, $\alpha_q$ so that (*) is true whenever $l\le q - 1$, and that you now have to choose $\alpha_{q+1}$ so that it's true for $k=1$, 2, $\dots$, $q-1$ and $l=q$.  Then, each of $B_1$, $B_2$, $\dots$, $B_q$ is a finite union of disjoint closed intervals, so each set $${\cal S}_k:=[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{q} B_m$$ is also a finite union of disjoint intervals (mostly open, but with one half-open one at the left.)

If we fix some interval $\cal I$, since $B_{q+1}$ has a grid structure—we remove one interval out of each five successive intervals of length $\alpha_{q+1}$—removing it will reduce the measure of $\cal I$ by multiplying it by a factor of approximately $4/5$:
$$|{\cal I}\setminus B_{q+1}|=\frac 4 5 |{\cal I}| + \epsilon(\alpha_{q+1}, {\cal I}).$$
There may be a small error, $\epsilon(\alpha_{q+1}, {\cal I})$, because of the finite size of the grid.
Lay $\cal I$ out on the grid, letting the integer $A\ge 1$ be minimal and the integer $B\le k_{q+1}+1$ maximal so that $A\le B$ and $[5A\alpha_{q+1}, 5B\alpha_{q+1}]\subseteq \cal I$; if $\cal I$ is so small that there are no such integers $A$ and $B$, set $A=B=0$.  Then
\begin{eqnarray*}|{\cal I}\setminus B_{q+1}|&\le& 4(B-A)\alpha_{q+1} + 10\alpha_{q+1}\\
&\le& \frac 4 5 |{\cal I}| + 10\alpha_{q+1},
\end{eqnarray*}
so
$$
\epsilon(\alpha_{q+1}, {\cal I})\le 10 \alpha_{q+1}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{q+1} B_m\right|
\le \frac 45
\left|[0,\pi)\setminus \bigcup_{m=k}^{q} B_m\right|+10 N_k \alpha_{q+1},
$$
where $N_k$ is the number of intervals in ${\cal S}_k$, $k=1$, $\dots$, $q-1$.  Since ${\cal S}_k$ doesn't have zero measure (it contains a small interval starting at zero) you can choose $\alpha_{q+1}>0$ small enough so that (*) holds for $l=q$ and each $k$.